# working with IQueryable; not working

Tags: c#, linq

I'm using linq-to-EF and I have this:

```
public IQeuryable<base01> GetData()
{
   var u = this.ObjectContext.base01;

   IQueryable<base01> u2 = u.OrderBy(o => o.article)
           .Select(l => new { Id = l.Id, article = l.article, lot = l.lot}) as IQueryable<base01>;

   return u2;
}
```

Basically, u contains the result of a query and I'm looking to sort and rearrange the columns. When I replace return u2 with return u I get what the result set filled but whe I go for return u2 I get a null.

What's the problem that I'm not seeing?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
as IQueryable<base01>
```

The problem is `as` - you are projecting to an anonymous type in your query not to `base01` - so `as` will return `null`. Instead create new instances of `base01` in your projection and remove the `as` operator:

```
IQueryable<base01> u2 = u.OrderBy(o => o.article)
                         .Select(l => new base01()
                          { Id = l.Id, article = l.article, lot = l.lot });
```

**Edit:**

If `u` is already an `IQueryable<base01>` and `base01` is one of your entities you do not need the `Select()` projection at all since *you already have the type you want*:

```
IQueryable<base01> u2 = u.OrderBy(o => o.article);
return u2;
```

Comment: If I remove the as IQueryable<base01> statement at the end it bugs red, what's wrong now?

Comment: What error does it show? I'm not psychic ;-) What type is `base01`? Would be good to show the definition

Comment: ok, the initial error was fixed: I added the new base01() statement. I'm now getting an empty result with the error when I click on the expand link "The entity or complex type "base01Model.base01" cannot be constructed in a LINQ to Entities query".

Comment: @frenchie: Updated answer: you don't need `Select()` at all

Comment: The problem is that I need to order AND change the column order; that's why I'm selecting the properties, to change the order of the columns in the IQueryable.

Comment: @frenchie: Then you are returning a different type of object - declare another class, project to that and return an `IEnumerable` of that class type

Comment: Ok, is it correct then to say that once I query the IQueryable and project to a list of objects of anonymous types (that's what I'm doing) I can't generate an IQueryable of type <base01> from this list?

Comment: @frenchie: That's correct - you cannot project back to an entity - also what do you mean by the "columns" in the IQueryable? It's properties?

Comment: ok, I meant properties; thanks for your answer and a better understanding of queryables. I'll stick to linq-to-sql and avoid linq-to-ef

Answer (score 0):

You cannot cast this way, use code below.

```
IQueryable<base01> u2 = u.OrderBy(o => o.article) 
       .Select(l => new base01 { Id = l.Id, article = l.article, lot = l.lot});
```

Comment: ok, that was the fix.  I'm now getting an empty result with the error when I click on the expand link "The entity or complex type "base01Model.base01" cannot be constructed in a LINQ to Entities query"

Comment: I added the new base01() statement. I'm now getting an empty result with the error when I click on the expand link "The entity or complex type "base01Model.base01" cannot be constructed in a LINQ to Entities query"